# Excel VBA: add a blank cell below every output

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little problem with my VBA code. I use the code below to display every date in a date range. So if the date range is 3 Dec - 5 Dec, it will display 3 Dec in cell E10, 4 Dec in cell E11 and 5 Dec in cell E12. This works fine, however I need to add 4 blank cells below every date (so 3 Dec will be in cell E10, but the 4th of December will be shown in cell E15 etc).

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control
' Check user input
    If Me.SdPicker.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an start date.", vbExclamation, "Start data error"
        Me.SdPicker.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.EdPicker.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the end date.", vbExclamation, "End date error"
        Me.EdPicker.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Write data to worksheet
With Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("X1")
    .Value = Me.SdPicker.Value
End With
With Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("Y1")
    .Value = Me.EdPicker.Value
End With
' Close the form to open Output sheet and implement date range
        Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Activate
        Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Columns(5).ClearContents

        Dim StartDate As Date
        Dim EndDate As Date
        Dim NoDays As Integer

        StartDate = Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("X1").Value
        EndDate = Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("Y1").Value
        NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 4

        Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("E10").Value = StartDate

        Worksheets("Projection_Daily").Range("E10").Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False

        Unload Me
End Sub
```

This is the code I currently use, I have tried to insert .Offset(4,0) to the code but with no luck. I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Loop condition like this:

```
i = 1   'To loop through the no of days
j = 10  'To start from row no 10

For i = 1 To NoDays  'Nodays = Enddate-Startdate
     Sheet1.Cells(j, 5).value = StartDate
     StartDate = StartDate + 1
j = j + 5  'To add a gap of 4 blank rows
Next i
```